# How to exclude multiple directories that match a glob pattern in "grep -R"?

Tags: linux, grep

I have some directories with names like "mm-yyyy" (01-2014) in current directory.  I want to grep the files in directories whose names have "2013".  How can I exclude directories whose names don't have "2013"?  I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
grep hill * -R --exclude-dir=*201[0-2]
```

It still went through all sub-directories to do grep.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you could use

```
grep -R hill *-2013
```

using `--exclude-dir` should work, too:

```
grep -R hill --exclude-dir=".*201[0-2]" .
```

without the quotes the asterisk would be expanded by bash. Additionally the wildcard for regular expressions is `.*`

```
. - matches any character
* - match any number of repetitions of the previous character, including none
```

Comment: Thanks, Max. It works.  But I wonder if I could achieve the same using --exclude-dir.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a solution with `--exclude-dir`

Comment: I tried the exclude-dir one but it didn't do anything.  There was no output.  It just sat there and waited for more user input.  So I added * after "hill" and it didn't work

Comment: ah ok, use . instead of *.* specifies all directories, and the exclude pattern triggers inside these - what is not, what you want

Comment: the dot works.  but "201[02]" excludes directories with "2010" and "2012" only. to exclude directories with "2010", "2011" and, "2012", i have to use this: "201[012]".  please update the answer so that i can mark it accepted.

Comment: Beware of grep version because `--exclude-dir` was introduced in 2.5.3
(On an old CentOS release 5.11 it isn't there, grep is 2.5.1).

Answer (score 56):

```
grep -r --exclude-dir={dir1,dir2,dir3} string_to_search_for *
```

Comment: Useful when there is no simple regex for the dirs in question

Comment: There is no regex magic here. Bash brace expansion is used to save on retyping the argument. The command above is interpreted as `grep -r --exclude-dir=dir1 --exclude-dir=dir2 --exclude-dir=dir3 string_to_search_for *`. Check out (http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) for more Bash magic.